# Can anyone explain this behavior in git-merge?

Tags: git, git-merge

The most recent commits in my local git repo are structured like

```
O-A-B
  \
   C
```

FWIW, `B` is in the master branch.  Changes have been made to `A` in both `B` and `C`.  I want to merge C back into B and preserve the changes from both in a new commit `D`

```
O-A-B-D
  \  /
   C
```

For instance, maybe `A` looks like

```
foo = true
bar =  1
```

and `B` looks like

```
foo = false
bar = 1
```

and `C` looks like

```
foo=true
bar = 2
```

and, finally `D` should look like

```
foo=false
bar = 2
```

So, I checked out `B` and gave the command to merge with `C`.  I was expecting that git would see the inconsistencies in the files, produce incomplete merge files, and tell me that I had to edit and commit them.  And I was ready to do that.  But that is not what happened.  Instead, git completely clobbered commit `B` with commit `C`, so that `D` was completely equivalent to `C`.  Git did not give me the chance to do any editing.  It just did an auto-merge without waiting for any input from me.

Well, I was able to back out the merge commit and then do the whole thing by hand using git difftool.  But this was a harder way.  Why did git not produce the files of the incomplete merge and then leave it to me to edit them?  I thought that was just the way git always did a merge between two inconsistent branches.

Comment: I would have expected the same as you. Do you use the rerere database? Do you have rerere.autoUpdate set? Did you receive a merge conflict during an earlier operation (e.g., a rebase or a cherry-pick), where you resolved it and committed the result?

Comment: @j6t   Appreciate the advice, but, honestly, I don't know what rerere is.  I'll look it up.  Of course, any links you have are much appreciated.

Comment: [`git rerere`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere). But you rarely run the command yourself. Once `rerere.enabled` is set, `git commit` and merging commands like `merge` and `cherry-pick` run it for you automatically.